# "This branch has conflicts that must be resolved" but it's already merged

Tags: git, github, pull-request, merge-conflict-resolution, git-merge-conflict

I merged a [PR](https://github.com/DaniSchenk/moment-feiertage/pull/8) with the GitHub web interface, which resolved in a successful [merge commit](https://github.com/DaniSchenk/moment-feiertage/commit/6ea0b7a08c8a5b5d81f836493235ad4c55b7d0e9).

Afterwards, GitHub is complaining *This branch has conflicts that must be resolved*. Does anybody know why or how to get the status *merged*?

Comment: What is in conflict? Can you show the conflict?

Comment: @AntoineWils just click the links in my description. It's a public repo

Comment: @AntoineWils the PR is already merged, so I don't know what the error is. Image from my Gitkraken-App: https://ibb.co/gTFST90

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You'll need to update your branch with new commits from master, resolve those conflicts and push the updated/resolved branch to GitHub.

```
git checkout master
git pull
git checkout <branch>
git merge master
[ ... resolve any conflicts ... ]
git add [files that were conflicted]
git commit
git push
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. Which brach do I have to check out the after master, @Smbat Pogosyan ?

Comment: To branch which you want to merge with master, I think.

Comment: I don't know why, but after merging master into RP-branch and merging RP again into master it worked. Now I merged the RP two times but at least Github isn't nagging anymore.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE 2022**

I used help on the [top](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56684701/15523781) but i get some git error !

I think was for new updates git !

so, I run this commands :

```bash
git checkout <branch>
```

Like : git checkout origin/main

```bash
git pull  <repository link when you forked>
```

```bash
git checkout <branch>
```

```bash
git merge <branch>
```

And now go to file and check your change!

```bash
git add
```

```bash
git commit
```

or

```bash
git commit -m "commit"
```

If your needed Signed-off-by: use ( -s ).

Finally:

```bash
git push origin HEAD:<name-of-remote-branch>
```